# Relation between Betti Numbers and Chromatic Number of a simple graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, graph-theory, graph-colorings, ideals

Is there a relation between the betti numbers of a graph considered as a simplicial complex and its chromatic number?

Typically the first Betti number is said to be the cyclomatic number of the graph. the betti numbers are also related to the free resolutions of the free module generated by the quotient of the polynomial ring in $n$ variables quotiented with edge ideal of the graph. Any thoughts? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Kalai and Meshulam posed several conjectures in the 1990s. Most can be found here: https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/when-a-few-colors-suffice/. Some of these conjectures have been proved in the past few years by Scott and Seymour https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04609.pdf and Chudnovsky, Scott, Seymour and Spirkl https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.00065.pdf.